# Disconnect image cache from opencart 3 image manager

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart2.3

When i upload any image for my Opencart 3 website, it takes close to 10 minutes for the image to appear in the image manager.

I discovered that the images are stuck in the cache before they upload to the main directory.

I have increased the values of my php.ini  and the sizes of my images are between 25kb to 50kb and deployed many speed optimization apps and  yet I still have the same delays.

Presently, I want to disconnect the cache from the image manager so all images gets loaded directly to the image manager

Please I need help

Comment: Did the answer below help? If so, please mark as accepted or note any issues

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to change how the Model returns files to the front-end in `\catalog\model\tool\image.php` right at the bottom of the file you'll find this code:

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $image_new;
} else {
    return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $image_new;
}
```

You can change it to:

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $image_old;
} else {
    return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $image_old;
}
```